# How to proof that $\forall non-empty sets A, B and C: formula thats too long...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all non-empty sets A, B and C: $A \cap B = \emptyset , A \cup C \not= \emptyset, B \cup C \not= \emptyset $ implies  $\exists x(x \notin A, x \notin B , x \in C) $

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. As a counterexample, consider $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $C=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Why is it in this situation not true? I knew that it wasnt true, but my friend isisted that it was, only i couldnt show a counterexamnple

Comment: @lederhoser: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here? It is not true because all of your conditions are satisfied, but there is no $x$ with the properties your conclusion wants.

Comment: @lederhoser There is not much to test in order to verify that this is a counterexample, is there?